# Getting "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" in production mode and no errors getting logged

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, logging, mysql-error-1045

I deployed my Rails app and am getting 500 Errors on all pages. My production.log isn't showing anything (which is a problem), but I did a 'script/console production' and tried to run a simple query (User.find :first) and it throws this:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

My database.yml file definitely has a password there and it's correct.

So, that plus no errors being logged to my production.log file is making me wonder what's up.

Any ideas where I'd start looking or what the issue could be?

Also, for what it's worth, I'm running Passenger on Apache.

UPDATE: Here's my database.yml file contents

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: website_development
  username: root
  password: secretz
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: website_test
  username: root
  password: secretz
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: website_production
  username: ttp_mysql
  password: secretz
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**NEW UPDATE:** I changed the mysql user so it wasn't running in root, but now I'm still getting the "Access denied for 'root'@'localhost'" bit...even though in production mode it shouldn't be running as 'root' at all.

Really really confused now.

Comment: Deleted my answer, but I'm going to reiterate my initial question: any reason you're logging into the database as **root** and not creating a more-limited user for your application?

Comment: Probably should change that. Will look into it after I get my application working again. :)

Comment: You are most probably using one config file and changing the other. Try finding out which config file is used.

Comment: Um...I wasn't aware there were multiple config files for the database and certainly not aware of how to change to a different config file to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the issue. I had added some files to my /models folder for doing some database migrations from an old database.

In those files I had "ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection" to connect to the database and somehow those were overriding what was in my database.yml file (even though I wasn't calling those files directly).

Either way...removing those solved the issue.

Thanks for taking the time to try to figure this out!

Answer (score 4):

The fact that it's trying to use the `root` account coupled with the fact that you're not seeing anything in your `production.log` file seems to suggest that the application isn't running in **production** mode.

To easily check if this is true or not, try adding the following line to the environment.rb file (near the top), restart the app, and see if you're still getting the same error:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "production"
```

**Note**: For obvious reasons, this is **not** good practice, so even if this works, I suggest finding out the root cause and removing this line from the file.  However, seeing as you're seeing issues on your production server, I'm hoping this answer will at least get you (back) up and running while you continue to diagnose *why* it wasn't running in production mode in the first place.

Comment: So I'm doing this now...but it actually looks like it's still trying to use my 'development' database.

Is there a way to verify which set of data is being used from the database.yml file?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and realized that I hadn't restarted my rails server. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue too. I closed all the terminals and restarted the server. It works fine!