# Ruby On Rails database error, Access denied for user (using password: NO), not root, in Production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

Edit: someone suggested that this post is a duplicate of another post. Please note, the big clue on that other post was the author of the post got an error message that said "root" was trying to reach the database. That is not the problem I face. I have the correct user in the error message.

---

Just installing a Rails 4.2 app that other developers have been working on.

The database is MySQL.

The database relies on VIEWS, which are locked to the user "nibble_prod". The user "nibble_prod" refers to the user we use in production.

We don't have great setup scripts, so I created a user on my machine manually:

CREATE USER 'nibble_prod'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'something';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'nibble_prod'@'localhost';

Then I edited:

```
  ~/.bashrc
  source ~/.bashrc
```

If I:

```
  printenv
```

I see:

```
  PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PASSWORD=something
```

In

```
  /config/database.yml
```

I have:

```
  production:
    <<: *default
    database: orim
    username: nibble_prod
    password: <%= ENV['PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

However, if I do:

```
   rake db:structure:dump RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get:

```
  /vagrant/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.19/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect': Access denied for user 'nibble_prod'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

Why is this not using the password?

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698066/getting-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no-in-prod?rq=1

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I do RAILS_ENV=production, so I am certainly in production. On that other question, the user had failed to activate the production environment.

Comment: The big clue on that other post was the author of the post got an error message that said "root" was trying to reach the database. That is not the problem I face. I have the correct user in the error message.

Comment: I find it frustrating when people mark a question as duplicate, without actually reading the details of the question.